# Updating model with Core 2.2

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

How do you handle the Id in a detail page with the newest ASP.NET Core 2.2 technology?

If I use a hiden field with the Id it gets passed when I click on save.
But when I comment it I wont get the Id.

```
<form asp-controller="Coach" asp-action="UpdateCoach" method="post">
@*<input asp-for="Coach.Id" type="hidden" />*@
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <td>Naam:</td>
        <td><input asp-for="Coach.CoachName" value="@Model.Coach.CoachName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Type coach:</td>
        <td>
            <select asp-for="Coach.CoachTypeId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.CoachTypes,"Id", "CoachTypeDescription"))">
                <option></option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Telefoon:</td>
        <td><input asp-for="Coach.CoachPhone" value="@Model.Coach.CoachPhone" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td><input asp-for="Coach.CoachEmail" value="@Model.Coach.CoachEmail" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Opslagen" class="btn btn-default" />
```

This is my Controller :

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateCoach(CoachViewModel coachViewModel)

    {
        return Redirect("/Coach/Coach");
    }
```

In coachViewModel I get all values expect the Id!

Comment: the id only exists after the record is saved on the database

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is for updating a existing model

Answer (score 0):

> How do you handle the Id in a detail page

Assuming this is an "edit" page for an entity that already exists in a database, then your options include:

- Store it in a hidden field so it's included in the `POST`.
- Use it as a URI path parameter or querystring parameter

  - e.g. `GET /users/{userId}` and `PSOT /users/{userId}` or `GET /users?userId={userId}` and `POST /users?userId={userId}`
- If the Id value can be determined from the current request (e.g. based on a `User`'s security `Claim` or something in session-state) then use that.

If this is a page to define data for a new entity that doesn't exist yet (assuming you're using `IDENTITY`/`AUTO_INCREMENT`), then it doesn't matter because you'll be doing an `INSERT` operation anyway and you should have a separate URI path (and Controller Action) for this operation anyway (i.e. so your code doesn't expect nor require any entity identifier in this scenario).

Comment: so as my sample code, hide the ID field . But is this a proper solution?

Comment: @user11208424 Yes, just make sure you add permissions checks to prevent users from updating entities they shouldn't be allowed to.